# Using Docker for MEAN Stack Application: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mean-stack

I am trying to use Docker for the first time. I have a MEAN stack app that I am trying to create a Dockerfile and docker-compose file for. My Node server is running and displaying the Angular front end, however I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when the app tries to make the initial requests to my Mongo database, and does not save data to the database either.

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```js
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```js
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And in my server.js file, I have these lines of code:

```js
const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/myDB'; 

// connect to mongodb
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I can't seem to figure out what might be causing this, any help would be greatly appreciated. When I run `docker container ls` it shows two containers, one for my app and one for mongo, but mongo does not appear to be working.

Edit: Here is the output of `docker container ls`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE          COMMAND         CREATED        STATUS        PORTS            NAMES
16451b5b6f9d  myapp_app          "npm start"     2 days ago     Up 2 days   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp  app
ad21af079c62   mongo    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago     Up 2 days   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongo
```

Comment: Could you share the output of the command `docker container ls `?

Comment: Yes, I added the output to the end of my post.

Comment: Seems to be a trouble with the volume mounted. Could you have another directory mounted on the host ? `./datax:/data/db` - Add this instead to your compose file. Or skip persistence for once and remove the volume mounted.

Comment: Thank you! If I remove the volume mounted the database does work, however I need this app to persist the data when deployed and updated in the future (if I'm understanding correctly, will it not persist without volumes?). Changing to `./datax:data/db` made no change, unfortunately.

Comment: You will have to create a volume and use it in your compose file. Alternately, you can mount your host directory.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!